# PHP - if statement echo's nothing if null

Tags: php, if-statement, null, echo

I have a script that displays job listings, it currently displays "(0)" if there are no listings in a particular category. I want it to display nothing if there are no listings and to display the actual count if there are. I also need to bring the brackets into the statement if possible, so they are not displayed if the value is "0". Ive played with php a little but this is beyond my basic knowledge.

This is the line that currently exists, I dug around a bit and tried to implement some ideas I found around and in the PHP manual, but to no avail. I hope this is enough info about he statement.

```
(<?php echo $sub->assignedcareers != null ? $sub->assignedcareers : 0; ?>)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($sub->assignedcareers) {
    echo "($sub->assignedcareers)";
}
```

Comment: Awesome!, worded a charm Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `assignedcareers` is an array, you can use **[count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)** to count the number of elements in it.

This amended statement will print the count if the array is not null and do nothing otherwise. It'll also print the count inside parenthesis.

```
<?php 
  if( $sub->assignedcareers != null )
  {
    echo "(" . count($sub->assignedcareers) . ")";
  }
?>
```

Comment: this almost worked but echoe'd a "1" for all categories empty or not, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Makes sense, since I was under the impression that `assignedcareers` was an array, but it sounds like it's actually an int, so count() would always return 1 since it was provided with a single element. deceze's solution would thus be the correct one. :)